In next-intl, without i18n routing, how to pass a locale value from the search params to the request config?
I'm using next-intl without i18n routing. As per the docs, it is set like this:
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
 
export default getRequestConfig(async () => {
  // Provide a static locale, fetch a user setting,
  // read from `cookies()`, `headers()`, etc.
  const locale = 'en';
 
  return {
    locale,
    messages: (await import(`../../messages/${locale}.json`)).default
  };
});

My app's locale can be changed via a search param https://mywebapp.com?lang=en.
I have tried saving the params into a cookie in the middleware, but it can't be read in the getRequestConfig function
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server"

export async function localeMiddleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = new URL(request.nextUrl.href)
  const langParam = url.searchParams.get("lang")
  
  const response = NextResponse.next()
  response.cookies.set("lang", langParam)
  return response
}

but it's not available when I read it
export default getRequestConfig(async () => {
  console.log(cookies().get("lang)) // null

Is there another way to do this?
